# Access Google cloud platform billing api

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-billing

Is there a way to allow/give consent to a developer to access my google cloud platform billing data ?

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

If it is your Google cloud platform billing data you're trying to give access to i believe it is possible. you just need to assign him(his email) as a billing administrator, he should be able to see billing stuff like receipts and such
I kinda followed this https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access

Comment: Well i want the developer to use the google cloud billing api to generate reports

Comment: Using api https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts/list

Comment: Do not assign "Billing Administrator" without understanding the power that role has. A better role for a developer needing access to billing data is `roles/billing.viewer` aka Billing Account Viewer.